# CSS3 pulse effect not working on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I want a pulse effect on the `div` when it is clicked ..

I have made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/MrdvW/591/) for it.

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse_animation {
    0% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
    30% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
    40% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.08); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
    60% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
    70% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.05); }
    80% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
}
```

**Pulse Animation code**

```
@-moz-keyframes pulse_animation{
0% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
    30% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
    40% { -moz-transform: scale(1.08); }
    50% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
    60% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
    70% { -moz-transform: scale(1.05); }
    80% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
    100% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
}
```

It's working on Chrome very well but not in Firefox ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added quotes around the animation name, which made it fail, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/MrdvW/593/

```
-moz-animation-name: pulse_animation;
```

Also, you don't need the -moz- prefixes anymore with the current firefox versions.

[Moz guide to animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations)

Answer (score 1):

you haven't add a vendor prefix for Firefox. `-moz-animation-name` which is required for older version of Firefox only. Latest Firefox version fully support the standard version.

`@keyframes your_animation_name` is a standard and valid by w3c. you should also include it.

it works well withe latest FF and latest IE. however prefix version still required for webkit based browser.